# Is graphql-js written in Vanilla JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, graphql-js

I started to learn `graphql-js` source code, but found it is difficult to determine whether the source code is written in `vanilla js` or `typescript`?

For example, the main entry file `src/graphql.js` has the following code:

```
import type { GraphQLSchema } from './type/schema';
import type { ExecutionResult } from './execution/execute';
```

I don't think the import type is standard `js` syntax. Can anyone please help explain what it is for?

Also, the following code looks like `TypeScript` to me, but the file extension is `js`, not `ts`:

```
function graphql( 
   schema: GraphQLSchema,
   requestString: string,
   rootValue?: mixed,
   contextValue?: mixed,
   variableValues?: ?{[key: string]: mixed},
   operationName?: ?string):: Promise<ExecutionResult> {}
```

Answer (score 0):

After asking the question, I did some research. Apparently `graphql-js` uses the [Flow Type](https://flow.org/), which is similar to `TypeScript`. James Kyles from Babel and Flow team explained the difference between `Flow Type` and `TypeScript` very well [here](https://discuss.reactjs.org/t/if-typescript-is-so-great-how-come-all-notable-reactjs-projects-use-babel/4887)